# Trigger success handler is finished executing, with nested ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have many nested ajax requests like below. I have a lot of things going on in the success function below, I need something like success that will **trigger when success is complete**. `complete(jqXHR, textStatus)` just seems to fire with `success` and I don't think [`.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) works.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/periods.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (d1) {
        //more nested ajax requests
    },
});
```

**SOLUTION**:

A `$.ajax()` replacement plugin called `$.fajax()` (finished + ajax) has been created. Please check it out and let me know what you think. https://github.com/reggi/fajax (It's pretty well documented).

Comment: By "trigger when success is complete" do you mean when the request completes successfully or when your success handler is finished executing?

Comment: When success handler is finished. `success` is triggered when the request completes.

Comment: That's going to be difficult to do globally, ajax is by design asynchronous, so without knowing what you're doing in "more nested ajax requests" there's not really an easy answer. Technically your success handler could be finished before your nested ajax requests finish.

Comment: @Kroehre I think I get it. I was just checking if their was a buit in - simple way to do this. But I guess not, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a wrapper function for jQuery.ajax to make this a little cleaner:

```
var started = 0, done = 0;
var globalHandler = function(){
    //do stuff when all success handlers are done
}
function handleAjax(args){
    var _success = args.success || function(){};
    args.success = function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        _success(jqXHR, textStatus);
        done++;
        if(done >= started)
             globalHandler();
    }
    var ajax = $.ajax(args);
    started++;
    return ajax;
}
```

usage

```
handleAjax({
    url: 'api/periods.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (d1) {
        //more nested ajax requests like this:
        handleAjax({...});
    }
});
```

This creates a closure so don't do any crazy memory-intensive stuff in there and you should be fine.

Comment: I do do some kind of crazy memory-intensive stuff =[ (looping ajax requests within loops of ajax requests and storing some of that data in an object)

Comment: I mean more within the context of the success handler closure, operations within your individual handlers wouldn't be part of the closure.

Comment: This essentially adds the event you're looking for, when all the success handlers have finished executing.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how I would integrate this is into my example? http://pastebin.com/fX04xhsx

Comment: put the first block in the answer above everything else in your code, then simply replace every occurrence of "$.ajax" with "handleAjax".

Comment: I didn't realize `handleAjax` was replacing `$.ajax`, thats pretty brilliant. This works! I would love to make it into a plugin that could be chain-able to the parent ajax request. Is this possible? It would be nice if I didn't have to change `$.ajax` as well. Thank's for your contribution!

Comment: Yep, i updated the function to return the jquery ajax object so you can chain.

Comment: Note you may want to experiment with incrementing the started variable before calling $.ajax, i can't decide if you should do it before or after.

Comment: I know I'm pushing, but I'm trying to get something like `$.fn.completion` function / plugin for jquery that would handle this? where `globalHandler()` == `.completion(function(){})` I don't even know how the function would get the `args` from `$.ajax` or get the other `$.ajax` requests within itself. Or where the counts would go. I guess I'll rule it out. lol

Comment: you could monkey patch jQuery.ajax so that $.ajax effectively becomes handleAjax and get exactly what you're asking for, but that could have adverse effects on other code.

Comment: Nice! I made a few additions: http://pastebin.com/YnFnD3qR. It doesn't really make sense to use $.fn since you aren't using this directly on a jquery object. However, you could change this a bit so that you could create instances of the cojax function and have more than one going at a time if you ever needed to.

Comment: A few! HA! I have much to learn =]. Is this ready to replace `handleAjax` and `globalHandler`? Where is `globalHandler` in your update? How do I implement it?

Comment: Yep, that replaces globalHandler. Now, you can call $.cojax instead, and to add handlers for when all success callbacks have been executed: $.cojax.addHandler(function(){//do stuff}); You can add as many handler as you want, they will be executed in the order they are added.

Comment: So freaking cool! I tried that though and `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addHandler'` its talking about `$.cojax({}).addHandler(function(){});`

Comment: Functions in javascript are basically just objects with some extra stuff. addHandler is actually a function within that object. So, you need to invoke it like you would normally invoke a function on a simple object: $.cojax.addHandler(function(){}); (no parenthesis on cojax)

Comment: You could modify that to chain like you're doing in your example, but then you wouldn't be able to chain onto the jquery ajax object. If that's what you want, return 'this' (without quotes) instead of the jquery ajax object

Comment: gotcha. trying to debug this now... =] cojax is seemingly more complex  lol `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined`

Comment: WORKS! I'm gonna post it on github eventually and continue this development!

Comment: oops, addHandler should have handlers.push not handler.push

Comment: I needz multiple instances! How do I do it?!?! I run it all in a button and I'm trying to make it so that if you press the button again it will still work. The first time the button is pressed `addHandler` runs once. the next it runs twice, the next 3 times. could we also clear the cache at the end of `addHandler`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite totally sure of what you're asking, so forgive me if I'm off-kilter, but I think you might want something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/periods.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(d1){
   //more nested ajax requests
  },
}).done(function(msg){
     alert("Every Ajax Call is Complete!");
});
```

Comment: `.done()` fires with success! `done()` and `success` are essentially the same thing. Is is not firing when success is finished.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe try creating a function that has your post-success code in it, and call it at the end of the success function.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `async:false` option? I ran into this problem at work just a couple minutes ago, and that solved my problem.

Comment: Its wayyyyyyy slower I'm preforming thousands of requests. Please check this out. https://github.com/reggi/fajax You want it to be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You may want .queue() or .Defered

```
$("#el").queue("queue_name",function(){        
    $.ajax({
       url: 'api/periods.json',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(d1){
           //more nested ajax requests
           $("#el").dequeue("queue_name"); // tell queue success is complete
       },
    });
}).queue("queue_name",function(){
   //do something you want when success is complete       
})
$("#el").dequeue("queue_name"); // start to execute
```

or $.Deferred()

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'api/periods.json',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(d1){
   var start = function(){
       var dtd = $.Deferred();
       //more nested ajax requests---------------
       $.post("xxx",function(){
           dtd.resolve(); // when success is complete
       });


       //----------------------------------------
       return dtd.promise();
   }
   start.apply(this).pipe(function(){ 
       //do something you want when success is complete 
   });

   },
});
```

Comment: My ajax request is inside a `.submit(function(event){`? How would this work?

Comment: If there are multiple nested ajax requests in there you'll still have the problem of knowing when all of the success handlers are finished executing.

Comment: then you can use $.when($.ajax(),$.ajax(),$.ajax()).done(function(){})

Comment: I thought the `$.Defered()` option was promising but alas it returns `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){` … everyting in start … `dtd.resolve();return dtd.promise();} has no method 'pipe'`

Comment: @Willy I'm looping ajax requests. `.when()` prolly won't work for that right?

Comment: Yeah, if they are looping ajax request. you must know when success is complete

Comment: try this start.apply(this).pipe(function(){...  it should be work

Comment: Be sure where dtd.resolve() is. I have edited my original sample.

Comment: I moved `dtd.resolve()` still didn't work, here is my code exact. http://pastebin.com/fX04xhsx feedback would be greatly accepted =]. I'm trying to get a trigger for when `success: function(d1){` is complete.

Comment: I removed `dtd.resolve()` and `start.apply(this).pipe(function(){` does not run.

Comment: I think deferred would be an excellent solution if he wanted to execute something when all ajax requests were finished, but he's wanting to know when all ajax requests are finished AND their success handlers have finished executing. On top of that we're not just dealing with a bunch of requests sent off at once, they are staggered because of nesting. That's what's making this tricky.

Comment: Yeah so the function in pipe will run "after" dtd.resolve(). Maybe you can take a look at http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/ "Creating your own Deferred". The page is super good.

Comment: @Willy thanks for sharing, deferreds are very cool. Enables very flexible patterns.

Comment: Do I misunderstand ? In his code it seems there are no two ajax requests at same time.

Comment: Line 30 is executed in a loop.